# In bootstrap 3, why isn't button aligning to the bottom of the column as the CSS states?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I'm trying to align a button to the bottom of a column. The only way I can seem to accomplish this is by assigning an explicit height and using absolute positioning. Since I don't want all columns to behave this way, I'm wondering if there's something built into Bootstrap 3 that would allow me to do this?

[image: Image of bootstrap 3 column layout]

```css
.m-t {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel blank-panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3 m-t">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 m-t">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 m-t">
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
              <option value="1">Female</option>
              <option value="2">Male</option>
              <option value="3">Unspecified</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 m-t">
            <label for="birthDate" class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
            <div class="input-group date" id="birthDateDiv">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
              <input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" class="form-control" id="birthDate" name="birthDate" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 m-t" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: flex-end;">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" id="addPerson">Add Person</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically need to add the missing `label` for the spacing. I've added also `.form-control` to the `.btn` as to allow for better display in mobile. Also consider hiding the dummy `label` on mobile using `.hidden-sm` or similar.

```css
.m-t {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel blank-panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3 m-t">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 m-t">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 m-t">
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
              <option value="1">Female</option>
              <option value="2">Male</option>
              <option value="3">Unspecified</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 m-t">
            <label for="birthDate" class="control-label">Birth</label>
            <div class="input-group date" id="birthDateDiv">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
              <input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" class="form-control" id="birthDate" name="birthDate" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 m-t" style="">
             <label for="dummy" class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
            <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" id="addPerson">Add Person</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The other answer was a little cleaner, but your solution allows me to implement it without turning the entire form group into a flex row... I wasn't trying to add a bunch of media queries to accommodate this. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. Not that I mind but I think my solution is cleaner because it doesn't enforce other css on bootstraps css.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align `button` to bottom, you should apply `css` settings to `form-group`. In other words:

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: flex; align-items: flex-end;">
```

[image]

Comment: This solution ends up overriding any properties on the flex row, and flips it from a column layout to a row. I'm not trying to add a bunch of media queries to make this work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 is deprecated.

Solution: Adapt to [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel blank-panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-8 mt-3 px-2 ms-md-auto mx-auto">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-8 mt-3 px-2 ms-md-auto mx-auto">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-8 mt-3 px-2 ms-md-auto mx-auto">
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <select class="form-select">
              <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
              <option value="1">Female</option>
              <option value="2">Male</option>
              <option value="3">Unspecified</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-8 mt-3 px-2 ms-md-auto mx-auto">
            <label for="birthDate" class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
            <div class="input-group date" id="birthDateDiv">
              <input id="dateofbirth" class="form-control" type="date" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1 col-8 mt-3 px-2 ms-md-auto mx-auto" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: flex-end;">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" id="addPerson">Add Person</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a large government organization. I can't just do that. We are migrating to BS 5, but it's a 12 month project. This is a short term solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Understood. Well, now you have your solution for when you migrate to B5. I figured I'd give an a modern solution with modern technologies. B3 hasn't been updated and has been 'retired' for 3+ years. I suggest you update sooner rather than later since Bootstrap 3 ["will no longer receive critical security updates."](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2019/07/24/lts-plan/). You'd think with a government organization security would be priority 1.